# Upgrade steps to ImageResizer to 3.4.2 & AWS SDK 2?

Tags: .net, amazon-s3, imageresizer

I'm currently using 3.4.1 with  and the original Image Resizer S3

I'm trying to do a couple of upgrades here like net451, mvc 5, web api 2 etc. and also move to the latest Amazon AWS SDK 2.0.8.2 & 3.4.2 of IR but the process is filled with errors as the new AWSSDK 2 says that it can't find the proper S3 package or a compatible one.

STEPS?
1. Should I remove AWS SDK 1 & IR 3.4.1 completely
1a. Then re-install AWS SDK 2 & IR 3.4.2 afterwards

Is there a proper way that has worked for people to get to the latest version of IR 3.4.2?

Comment: Can you post your messages or logs?

Comment: that's a great question, how should I proceed? in my NuGet, the only thing left to install are the AWSSDK 2 and the ImageResizer packages for 3.4.2 --> which ones should I install first? or should I remove the old AWSSDK 1 & IR first?

Comment: When in doubt, remove AWSSDK and IR completely, then re-install IR and let it install AWSSDK and any required binding redirects.